# Change variable type inside main() C++

Tags: c++, types, program-entry-point

I have this code , i need output **x** variable as double (3.14) **without changing anything in the main function**

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 3.14;
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

What should i do ?

Comment: the value of `x` is `3`. You can write `std::cout << x << ".14";` Whats the point of this exercise?

Comment: no) i can't change anything , even std::cout

Comment: You could overwrite the int() operator, but I don't see why anyone would do that

Comment: this question makes no sense. You cannot change the output without changing the code

Comment: you can add code before main?

Comment: The point is make something (maybe) outside of the main to output 3.14, and do not change any symbol of code inside main

Comment: there's something missing here, doing something like `#define int double` is undefined behavior, you aren't allowed to redefine keywords.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions, one correct and one your professor probably wants.

1. The correct solution (one method, there are other similar ones). 
   Add this right after the `#include` line:

   ```
    int main() {
        double x = 3.14;
        std::cout << x << "\n";    
        return 0;
    }
    #if 0
   ```

   Add this at the end of the file:

   ```
    #endif
   ```
2. The incorrect solution for your professor.
   Add this line before `main`:

   ```
    #define int double
   ```

   - Why is this incorrect? Because `#define`ing a reserved word is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/).

   > [macro.names] A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords [...]

   - Why do I think your professor probably wants this? Because I've seen a few C++ assignments, and observed that their authors all too often disregard and abuse the C++ standard.
   - Your professor might want the first solution instead. I have no way to predict that.